# Перезагрузка ПК в определенное время или при зависание

Tags: python, windows, winapi

На удаленке находится ПК,порой он зависает и ему требуется перезагрузка,решил написать скрипт на python, который в определенное время будет перезагружать пк, с этим проблем нет, но мне интересен вопрос, как можно определить момент, что компьютер зависнет? Можно ли через python опрашивать загрузку ЦП И ОП ? Если да, то при каких значениях отправлять в ребут. Также рассматриваю вариант с GSM-розеткой, но хотелось бы знать,реально бы решить данную проблему без неё.

Comment: *как можно определить момент, что компьютер зависнет?* Программно, ага... как человек может определить, что он умер? Перезагрузка зависшего компа - только внешним воздействием. Скажем, через IP-KVM. При некоторых типах "зависания" может сработать настройка автовыключения в БИОС - не при всех (без гарантии), да и то лишь если таковая есть.

Comment: Я так полагаю лучше все-таки использовать GSM-розетку?

Comment: Да, что-то вроде http://www.netping.ru/products/upravljaemye-rozetki-ip-pdu

Comment: А перезагрузка в назначенное время без всякого скрипта shutdown /R /F в планировщике

Comment: Я думал что в питоне есть библиотеки благодаря которым можно будет перехватить нагрузку и отправить резко в ребут.

Comment: Гугли в сторону `usb-watchdogs`.

Comment: Отличная идея, спасибо за наводку.